# randomly sample a subset of a file in command-line without replacement

Tags: linux, file, unix, command-line, shuffle

I followed this thread [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/108581/how-to-randomly-sample-a-subset-of-a-file) to randomly shuffle data from a very large file. As pointed in that thread, shuf exhausts memory and takes a long time. So I ended up using the perl command
`perl -ne 'print if (rand() < .01)' huge_file.csv > sample.csv`
and works pretty efficient. However, I noticed it selects duplicated rows. I was wondering if there is any way to set the replacement to False to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

That bit of perl can only print duplicates if your source data has duplicate lines. You can remove them with something like

```
sort -u bigfile.csv | perl -ne 'print if (rand() < .01)' > sample.csv
```

`sort` is quite good at sorting large files without eating all your memory. You could also remove duplicates after picking the random sample lines with the similar

```
perl -ne 'print if (rand() < .01)' bigfile.csv | sort -u > sample.csv
```